# How to prove that $\ln x\leq x-1 \forall x>0$?

Tags: analysis

I need to prove that $\ln x\leq x-1 \forall  x>0$, using the Mean value theorem.

For $x=1$, the equation is true.

So, for starters I'll check for $x>1$.

By applying the aforementioned theorem for $$f(t)=\ln t / [1,x]$$ we know that there is  a $c\in(1,x)$ with

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\ln c=\frac{\ln x}{x-1}$$

And here I am stuck.

I know that $c>1$ thus $\ln c >\ln 1$ thus $\ln c>0$

But I don't know how to use that to prove what I need to prove.

Comment: $$1-\frac 1 x=\int_1^x t^{-2}dt\leqslant \int_1^x t^{-1}dt\leqslant  \int_1^x 1 dt=x-1$$ when $x\geqslant 1$. To reverse things, take $0<y<1$ and set $x=y^{-1}>0$. You'll get the very same inequality.

Comment: You should have $\dfrac 1 c = \dfrac{\ln x}{x-1}$, since $f'(c)=1/c$.  Then use the fact that $1/c<1$ if $c>1$ and $1/c>1$ if $0<c<1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I've posted an answer below expanding on my comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's do the case where $x>1$:
\begin{align}
& & f'(c) & = \frac{\ln x - \ln 1}{x-1} = \frac{\ln x}{x-1} \\[10pt]
\Longleftrightarrow & & \frac 1 c & = \frac{\ln x}{x-1} \\[10pt]
\Longleftrightarrow & & (\text{something less than 1}) & = \frac{\ln x}{x-1} \\[10pt]
\Longleftrightarrow & & (\text{something less than 1})\cdot(x-1) & = \ln x \\[10pt]
\Longleftrightarrow & & \ln x & < x-1
\end{align}

The case in which $0<x<1$ is done similarly.

Comment: It's hard to see why the repetition of "something less than ..." adds to the argument, why not just use $(x-1)/c$, then say "and $c>1$ in the final line.

Comment: Because the only thing about $c$ that matters is that $1/c$ is less than $1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You're missing some quantifiers for your propositions to be really equivalent (the term $c$ isn't defined): $\exists c\in(1,x)$ in the first two propositions, the third then reads as $0<\dfrac{\ln x}{x-1}<1$ and we're done.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** as $\log' x = 1/x$:
$$
\log x - \log  1 = \frac{x-1}{c_x}
$$

for some $c_x\in (1,x)$.

Comment: why $\log$ and not $\ln$ ?

Comment: I prefer $\log$ but it is a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$f(x):=\log x-x+1\implies f'(x)=\frac1x-1=0\iff x=1$$

and since

$$f''(x)=-\frac1{x^2}<0\;\;\forall\,x\implies x=1\;\;\text{is a maximum point} \implies$$

$$\forall\,x>0\;,\;\;f(x)\le f(1)=0$$

which is the wanted inequality.

Comment: But this doesn't use the theorem I mentioned,does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$e^x \ge 1+x$,
take the log
(so
$x \ge \ln(1+x)$),
and replace $x$ with
$x-1$.

I know this doesn't 
use the MVT,
but that's the way
the cookie bounces.

Comment: Well, how do you prove $e^x\geqslant 1+x$...?